# Not seeing scope in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a controller that passes two variables to my view via $scope. I can display those variables in the view.

In my view I have a directive, where I pass in the two variables to the directive scope.

Here is my directive:

```
.directive('notes', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl:'views/directives/notes-tpl.html',
    scope:{
      time:'=',
      unit:'='
    },
    controller:['$scope',function($scope){

      console.log('Current Time Stamp: ' + $scope.time);
      console.log('Current Unit Stamp: ' + $scope.unit);

      };

    }]
  };
})
```

and here is my html:

```
 <notes time='currentTimeStamp' unit='currentUnitStamp'></notes>
```

Problem is my console.log() shows them as undefined.

I'm calling the directive from a modal:

```
<!-- NOTES MODAL -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="notesModal.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ng-click="close()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></a>
        <h3 class="modal-title">Notes</h3>
    </div>

    <notes currentTimeStamp='{{currentTimeStamp}}' currentUnitStamp='{{currentUnitStamp}}'></notes>

</script>
```

Comment: works fine here:  http://plnkr.co/edit/lXctOKdJvqsy4zhVqhCk?p=preview.  are you *sure* that your properties have values?

Comment: @Claies, that is so strange. I display the scope results on the view where directive sits, so I know it's getting form the Controller to the View. But showing up undefined in my console.log within the directive.

Comment: Just do what Claeis did: post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. You'll probably find your own mistake while doing so.

Comment: Are your properties being assigned asynchronously from a service?  That's one thing that would cause the behavior you are describing, but this is still not a problem with this directive code, so a more complete example of your issue is necessary.

Comment: @Claies, I am. I'll have time to put an example up in about an hour and will do that.

Comment: Here is a plunker, where I have actual code: https://plnkr.co/edit/dK2O6JH76qvNoUsrLnbl?p=catalogue

Comment: the edit to your question to add the Notes Modal immediately shows the problem.  you went from `<notes time='currentTimeStamp' unit='currentUnitStamp'></notes>` to `<notes currentTimeStamp='{{currentTimeStamp}}' currentUnitStamp='{{currentUnitStamp}}'></notes>`.  You should not be using expressions in this HTML call.

Answer (score -1):

After seeing your example a new guess:

That's your HTML for calling the directive

```
<notes currentTimeStamp='{{currentTimeStamp}}' currentUnitStamp='{{currentUnitStamp}}'></notes>
```

1. But your `notes.js` hasn't any binding for this.

   ```
   return {
       ...
       scope: {
           currentTimeStamp="",
           currentUnitStamp=""
       }
       ...
   }
   ```
2. You need to pass this into your directive like this:

   ```
   <notes current-time-stamp='currentTimeStamp' current-unit-stamp='currentUnitStamp'></notes>
   ```

   Pay attention to the `current-time-stamp` instead of `currentTimeStamp`.
   Check out the **Normalization** section.

   https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

I hope this one will solve your issue.

---

Another guess:

Could it be you are updating "out of angular" in pure JS.
So angular doesn't know it has to update your values.

Let's say you would update some values on the `click` Event. Now we are using angulars ng-click for updating and calling a method (so angular would kick of the digest cycle by itself and would update the values).

Like this: `ng-click="updateTimeStamp()`

Now for some reason we don't use angular, but instead a *native event listener*:
`element.addEventListener("click", updateTimeStamp);`

So if we want now update the scope and its values, we have to kick of the digest cycle for example with a `$timeout` service.

More Information about the digest cycle: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

For verification put a `$timeout(angular.noop);` at the end of the listener where you set the values.

Example:

```
myElement.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var newTime = takeMeFromSomewhere;
    $scope.time = newTime;
    // Angular doesn't know to update the binding!
    $timeout(angular.noop);
    // now you kicked off the digest cycle and angular will update the values
});
```

Comment: Could this be because the directive is within a modal and the modal has it's own scope?

Comment: Yes, therefore you need to pass the data to the scope of your notes directive.